# How can I run my function in a thread in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, progress

I have a function that dynamically creates all my user interface.

What can I do to show a dialog progress while my function is executing, and then dismiss the dialog when my function has finished the user interface?

This is an example of my code:

Sorry, I'm new to android, it is hard for me to understand some code... I will write my code here...

I have this function:

```
 public void principal() {
        //CODE TO CREATE ALL THE USER INTERFACE DYNAMICALLY
    }
```

and I have the asyncTask like this:

```
public class EjecutarTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(StadioNenaActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando..");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {


        Principal();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

When I execute the asynctask in the onCreate, it crashes:

```
new EjecutarTarea().execute();
```

Comment: ALL View modification must be done in the UI Thread. Do all the loading that needs to be done in `doInBackground()` then you manage your View stuff in `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It gives a fantastic and easy way to load stuff in the background and them paste views in the main thread.

Here is an example of my AsyncTask:

```
private class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        private ProgressBar mProg;
        private TextView mLoadingText;

        @Override protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProg = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.launcherbar_loadprogress);
            mProg.setTouchDelegate(null);
            mProg.setClickable(false);
            mProg.setLongClickable(false);
            mProg.setOnTouchListener(null);
            mProg.setMax(100);

            mLoadingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.launcheractivity_loadingwhat);
        }

        @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_log, 29, 250);
            LOG.setContext(LauncherActivity.this);
            LOG.setDebug(true);

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_database, 43, 250);
            AppionDatabase.setContext(LauncherActivity.this);

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_sensors, 57, 250);
            Sensor.init(LauncherActivity.this);

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_jobs, 71, 250);
            Job.init(LauncherActivity.this);

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_workbenches, 86, 250);
            WorkbenchState.init(LauncherActivity.this);

            setProgressAndSleep(R.string.loading_application_state, 100, 250);
            ApplicationState.setContext(LauncherActivity.this);
            startService(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, BluetoothConnectionService.class));

            return null;
        }

        @Override public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
            mLoadingText.setText(prog[0]);
            mProg.setProgress(prog[1]);
        }

        @Override public void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, HomescreenActivity.class));
        }

        private void setProgressAndSleep(int text, int progress, int duration) {
            try {
                publishProgress(new Integer[] {text, progress});
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.e(TAG, "Failed to sleep thread while loading Application Contexts!", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit NOTE I recommend not keeping the `setProgressAndSleep(int, int int)` method. I only use it cause it loads too fast and I really wanted the loading bar. :-P

Answer (score 0):

All changes in Android UI will makes in **UI Thread**. To run your function in UI thread you need to use mathos runOnUIThread() from activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Hope it help you!

Comment: i used the runOnUIThread() in the doInBackground(), but it does not shows the dialog!

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is, probably, to use [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) to have temporary view with progress bar while you construct other view. Do operations that take time in `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask` but actual operations on UI such as flipping the view must be done in `postExecute()` or via `runOnUIThread()`. Progress updates may be done in `onProgressUpdate()`